# How to import a non eclipse (Rational Application Development) struts application into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, configuration, struts, ibm-rad

I'm trying to import Struts application into eclipse which is developed in IBM-RAD. But When I import using `File > Import > Existing Project`, it does not recognize it as a struts app.

Comment: Please show the content of the `.project` file.

Comment: An **Existing** project is one that's already stored as a project for the workspace, where you have a `.project` file present and more. You need to go back and import the original development project, with sources, rather than the finished application.